# how to add database in a new cluster in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6, pg-ctl

I am using

```
sudo pg_createcluster -u=$USER --datadir=candisDatabase -l=candisDatabase/candis.psql.log 9.6 candisCluster
```

to create a new database cluster with the specified directory as `candisDatabase` under the account $USER (which is 'rupav').

```
pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster        Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 candisCluster2 5433 online   rupav    candisDatabase               candisDatabase/candis.psql.log
9.6 main           5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

cluster is created successfully, and am able to run/start the new cluster and server candisCluster2 with `pg_ctlcluster 9.6 candisCluster2 start` successfully

following is the status of the new cluster (using `pg_ctlcluster 9.6 candisCluster2 status`) :

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres "-D" "candisDatabase" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/candisCluster2/postgresql.conf"
```

Now that server is listening on 5433 port, how can I add create role, database and password in the given cluster. By default (after postgresql installation) I can do `sudo -u postgres psql` to enter into the psql shell.

In short, I would like to have all my tables in the data directory specified, as `candisDatabase` which is owned by user different from `postgres`.

**System details**:
I am on 'Ubuntu 17.10 (Oracle VM, host being windows)' and postgresql version is 9.6

Comment: given that you specified user you probably don't want to su to postgres, su to the user instead.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you specified user you don't want to su to `postgres`, su to the user you specified instead.

if it's you just do

```
psql "port=5433 dbname=postgres"
```

Comment: Ok, so since I am already logged in as the user, 'rupav', I typed `psql`, which gave me output as : "psql: FATAL:  role "rupav" does not exist"

Comment: you need to specify the port number of the new cluster

Comment: output of running `psql "port=5433 dbname=postgres"`:
```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"? ```

Comment: pg_lsclusters output currently: 
```
Ver Cluster       Port Status Owner    Data directory                         Log file
9.6 candisCluster 5433 online rupav    /home/opensource/candis/candisDatabase /home/opensource/candis/candisDatabase/candis.psql.log
9.6 main          5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main           /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```