# Adding a database in a new cluster created on postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-17.10

I have created a database cluster in PostgreSQL-9.6 using `pg_createcluster` command with user (-u) specified different from default postgres. I would like to know how to add a new/existing database into this cluster instead of the default 'main' cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Conect to the template1 or postgres  database in the new cluster and execute sql 
`CREATE DATABASE` etc

Comment: Jasen can you please check this also (posted this a week back) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313244/how-to-add-database-in-a-new-cluster-in-postgresql . 
Can you elaborate how to "connect" in the first place.
I dont get your point of how to connect template1 or postgres database in the new sql.
Thanks.